# ReferenceError: document is not defined when connecting python backend to javascript frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

Im trying to make a program where the frontend is Node.js and the backend is Flask

Frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  
    <title>PreFab Davao</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Backend (The code I am trying to access):

@DBretriever.route('/getProjectDetails/<project_id>', methods = ['GET'])
def get_Project_Details(project_id): #gets project details from project ID
project_Details = []
found_Project = projects_collection.find_one({"project_id": project_id})

```
if found_Project == None:
    print("Error Code: e0102db; Project ID  Not Found")
    return "e0102db"
else:
    found_id = projects_collection.find_one({"project_id": project_id}, {"project_id": 1, "_id" : 0})
    project_id = found_id['project_id']
    project_Details.append(project_id)
    
    found_name = projects_collection.find_one({"project_id": project_id}, {"project_name": 1, "_id" : 0})
    project_name = found_name['project_name']
    project_Details.append(project_name) 

    found_status = projects_collection.find_one({"project_id": project_id}, {"project_status": 1, "_id" : 0})
    project_status = found_status['project_status']
    project_Details.append(project_status) 

    found_tasks = projects_collection.find_one({"project_id": project_id}, {"tasks": 1, "_id" : 0})
    tasks = found_tasks['tasks']
    project_Details.append(tasks) 

    return project_Details
```

as a kind of bridge between the two, I created a new JS file contain functions the frontend can easily access (I did it because multiple people are working on this)

"Bridge" JavaScript File:

```
function getProjectDetails(){

    const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript'

    $.ajax({
        url:"/getProjectDetails/<project_id",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }

    });
}

getProjectDetails();
```

the problem arises when I try to call `getProjectDetails()` it gives me `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: _"...even though jquery is already declared?"_ - jQuery is not relevant for that error/problem.

Comment: `document` should be always available - unless the script is not executed in the context of a web site.

Comment: Oh sorry about the title, I thought the problem stems from jquery (i am kind of still a beginner at this) but yeah that means the document is not available in my code. Ill look into my code more considering that